# I am not able to enter numeric value in text box of type input

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to enter numeric value using sendkeys, input type text box is not accepting the numeric values.
The driver is able to click the textbox but the values are not passing. Thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

DOM for the Text box field:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedStart" id="outlined-bare" name="application_amount|FABOX" type="text" value="">
```

I tried using javascript. But it is not working

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you submit some code and what is the spesific problem.

Edit: Works for me. I guess you are using material-ui? Is this pure JS or do you use any framework (react, angular, vue)?

Comment: any specific reason you tag this as "java"?

Comment: Can you paste the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your number in string format. 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='application_amount|FABOX']")).sendKeys("12345667");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a delay once you click on the text box using Thread.sleep(). 
Also check if the textbox supports alphanumeric or just alphabets.